# Check val of multiple input fields and if there are no empty create new input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when the user selects a file to create additional input for file, but if one of the created input fields is empty to not create a new one

Html:

```
<div class="pickerColors">
  <div class="color"><input class="selectFile" id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  function test(){
        var totalFields = $('.selectFile').length;
        for(i=0;i<totalFields;i++){
            if($('.selectFile').eq(i).val()==""){
                return false;

            }


        }
    }
    $('body').on('change', '.selectFile', function () {
        var parent =  $(this).parent().attr("id");
        test();
       if(test() != false){
           $('#'+parent).append('<input class="selectFile" id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />');
       }

        });
```

Comment: You’re creating multiple inputs with the same ID. Can’t do that.

Comment: `$('#sortpicture').length;` should only ever return `0` or `1` (by design), since - as terrymorse already noted - an `id` must be unique within the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
function isEveryInputEmpty() {
    var notEmpty = true;

    $('.newImage').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            notEmpty = false;
            return false; // we've found a non-empty one, so stop iterating
        }
    });

    return notEmpty;
}

$('body').on('change', '.newImage', function () {
    var parent =  $(this).parent().attr("id");

   if(isEveryInputEmpty() == true){
        $('#'+parent).append('<input  class="newImage" id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />');
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things:

1. you shouldn't be creating elements with multiple IDs
2. your inputs should not share the same name if you're sending to the server, you should send multiple values by appending `[]` to the end of the name
3. jQuery is unnecessary, if you aren't already loading it for something else, consider avoiding it
4. you can detect if inputs have a value using the `Array.prototype.some` method

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target
  if (tgt.classList.contains('selectFile')) {
    let container = tgt.closest('.color')
    
    if (!isEmptyInputAvailable()) {
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = '<input class="selectFile sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic[]" />'
      container.append(div)
    }
  }
})

function isEmptyInputAvailable() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.sortpicture')
  return Array.from(inputs).some(input => input.value == '')
}
```

```html
<div class="pickerColors">
  <div class="color"><input class="selectFile sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic[]" />
  </div>
</div>
```